# How do you track an active file in the project list in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

In Visual Studio, there is an option to "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer". That is, to keep the file you are working with in the editor selected in your file list. Is there an option for this in Android Studio?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In the Project View there there will be a gear icon on heading Tab. Click on that an check the option "**Autoscroll from Source**" .

[image: autoscroll]

Comment: Update on Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1, you can check the option "Always Select Opened File"

Answer (score 13):

This option has been renamed to `Always Select Opened File` in the newer version.

[image]

Comment: Nice, couldn't find it. I almost thought they had removed it.